# Websockets - Guaranteed full Messages?

Tags: html, google-chrome, websocket, em-websocket

When an "onmessage" event fires in the web socket protocol are you guaranteed the full message  or is it more like a straight TCP connection where you buffer the data first and then try to extract packets.

Comment: This comes to mind http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2011/07/websockets-is-a-stream-not-a-message-based-protocol.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is protocol level support for fragmented messages and streaming. But this behavior is not represented in the current Javascript API, ([reference](http://old.nabble.com/WebSocket-framing-td32304743.html)). So yes, if you receive a message, it is indeed an entire message even if it was sent as many fragments.